# Collectstatic - permission denied, pythonanywhere bash terminal

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to use the `collectstatic` command in pythonanywhere's bash terminal:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

But I get:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/static'

Please can anyone help? I've been trying to fix this for two days now.

Here's the full error :

> nomadpad-virtualenv) 11:51 ~/nomadpad (master)$ python manage.py collectstatic Copying '/home/DMells123/.virtualenvs/nomadpad-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djang o/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/inline-delete.svg' Traceback (most recent call last): File "manage.py", line 22, in  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) File "/home/DMells123/.virtualenvs/nomadpad-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django /core/management/init.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute() File "/home/DMells123/.virtualenvs/nomadpad-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django /core/management/init.py", line 356, in execute self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv) File "/home/DMells123/.virtualenvs/nomadpad-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django /core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv self.execute(*args, cmd_options) File "/home/DMells123/.virtualenvs/nomadpad-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django /core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute output = self.handle(*args, options) File "/home/DMells123/.virtualenvs/nomadpad-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django /contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 199, in handle collected = self.collect() File "/home/DMells123/.virtualenvs/nomadpad-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django /contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 124, in collect handler(path, prefixed_path, storage) File "/home/DMells123/.virtualenvs/nomadpad-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django /contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 364, in copy_file self.storage.save(prefixed_path, source_file) File "/home/DMells123/.virtualenvs/nomadpad-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django /core/files/storage.py", line 54, in save return self._save(name, content) File "/home/DMells123/.virtualenvs/nomadpad-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django /core/files/storage.py", line 321, in _save os.makedirs(directory) File "/home/DMells123/.virtualenvs/nomadpad-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok) File "/home/DMells123/.virtualenvs/nomadpad-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok) File "/home/DMells123/.virtualenvs/nomadpad-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs mkdir(name, mode) PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/static'

**Static Settings**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR, ]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'posts/media')
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Looks like your static dir is set to the root of the filesystem (`/static`) - most OS's aren't going to let you create a directory there without escalated privileges. Set it to a path you do have write access to... (it might be you just don't want the `/` there)

Comment: Please post your full STATIC_* settings. I suspect you are confused between STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you Daniel - I've actually just fixed it I believe. I was missing a bit from the static root, it should have been posts/static.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was missing a bit from the `STATIC_ROOT`, it should have been `posts/static`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but if you have:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

It tries to create a new "static" directory in root "/" path.

I changed it for:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
```

Additionally, in [Django documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files) there is something about that.